# How to setup WOL through WAN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My desktop computer is connected with Wfi router through an Ethernet cable.

And I can wake my computer through an android smartphone using an app.

While waking up computer through an android smartphone, smartphone is connected with the same wifi router.

WOL through LAN is working for my desktop computer.

I need to setup WOL through WAN so that I can turn on my desktop computer from anywhere through Internet.

My router link is [this](https://fccid.io/pdf.php?id=2806443), DHCP is enabled in my router and IP is dynamic.

How to setup WOL through WAN?

Regards

UGN

Answer (score 1):

This is the general procedure:

1. Put your target machine on a static IP address
2. Add a permanent static ARP entry for that machine on your router. Not all consumer home gateway routers have an easy way to do this. This is a critical step that is often overlooked.
3. Add a port mapping (forwarding rule) on the router to map a UDP port (usually port 9 I think) to the static IP of your target.
4. Note the MAC address of the Ethernet card of your target.
5. (Use a tool to) Craft a packet that contains the WOL magic pattern (ffffffffffff + 16 copies of the target MAC address), inside a UDP packet to port 9 on the public IP address of your router.

For best results, test this from the WAN side of your router, in case your router doesn't do NAT loopback.

Comment: How start these steps practically? I did Google search also for its resolutions. Perhaps, freedns.afraid.org can be helpful for this. And apart from this, I believe DDNS and Port forwarding can be helpful. I signed up freedns.afraid.org and gone through freedns.afraid.org/guide/dd-wrt/ also. All search and links mashed up whole process. Please guide me, how to configure freedns.afraid.org, DDNS and Port forwarding?